First and second date from table in SQL Server
I have 2 tables.
User ID
And orders
How would I go about finding the first and second date for userid?



USERID
name
order id




1
P1
100


2
P2
101


3
P3
102


4
P4
103


5
P6
104






Userid
Orderid
date completed




1.
10001
Sept 1, 2023


1.
10002.
Sept 2, 2023


2.
10003.
Sept 3, 2023


2.
10004.
Sept 4, 2023


2.
10005.
Sept 4, 2023



Followed another example but kept on erroring out. I'm expecting to find the first and second order dates fornuserid 1 and 2.

Use ROW_NUMBER(). Partition by USERID ORDER BY date completed. WHERE RN=1 OR RN=2
